# ¿detectar si una app esta instalada en react native?

Tags: android, typescript, react-native, android-intent, webview

Estoy desarrollando una app con react native y es una app 95% webviews, tengo una webapp que tambien estoy desarrollando yo, y cuando abro la app android invoco las webviews de la webapp.
Entonces hay una webview con un boton que dice "Ir a Youtube", esto desde la webapp me redirige a https://www.youtube.com/ (muy facil), pero desde android me abre el navegador, yo quisiera que el usuario desde android, cuando apriete el boton "Ir a Youtube" haya una logica que detecte:

1- Si la app youtube esta instalada, lo rediriga a la app.

2- Si la app youtube no esta instalada, lo rediriga a la playstore para que el usuario pueda descargarse la app de youtube.

Vi en varios post que dicen de definir en AndroidManifest un intent con el package de youtube, yo intente hacer eso pero no me funciono.
A continuacion dejo el codigo de la webview donde tengo el boton con las redirecciones:

```
const Youtube = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const currentPlatform = getOSName();

    const handleClickApp = () => {
        switch (currentPlatform) {
            case 'Windows':
            case 'Mac OS':
            case 'Linux':
                router.push('https://www.youtube.com/');
                break;
            case 'Android':
                router.push('https://www.youtube.com/');
                break;
            case 'iOS':
                router.push('https://www.youtube.com/');
                break;
            default:
                router.push('https://www.youtube.com/');
                break;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar [react-native-check-app-install](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-check-app-install) y mediante el "package name" de la app que deseas saber si esta instalada en este caso Youtube:

```
com.google.android.youtube
```

realizarias la comprobación de esta forma:

```
AppInstalledChecker
    .isAppInstalledAndroid('com.google.android.youtube') 
    .then((isInstalled) => {
        //isInstalled tiene valor "true" si la app se encuentra instalada, en caso contrario el valor sera "false"
    });
```

Comment: okey, esto lo tengo que hacer desde la app mobile o desde la webapp? en caso de ser en la app mobile lo tengo que hacer en el MainApplication.java?

Comment: eh probado esto que dices y no logre hacerlo funcionar, me tira un error de "Cannot read property 'pkgName' of undefined", probe hacer lo que dicen en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44005242/how-can-i-check-app-installed-in-react-native-code. pero tampoco logro que funcione, hay alguna otra alternativa o solucion a esto?